# Getting JSON data filtered by date and make a new array out of it

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

So I am having this problem with Javascript and JSON data. 
When I fetch data from a certain URL I get the data in a JSON file with strings.
Now my problem is. One of these strings is a date which I need to use so when the date is less than current date, that it will form a new string out of it so I can properly display data to HTML I am designing. ?

Idea of my project is that it displays events listed for that day and I want to display only upcoming events, not the ones that already ended.

Note The date is in ISO_8601 format. Also I am new to scripting. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of the JSON data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Simeon said my opinion is same, I would like to add little bit more information with him.

When you got the dates you need to do two things,

- First is checking if it is a **valid** date
- Its **upcoming/future** date or not.

You haven't added the example dates JSON in question, I am assuming you have a JSON like below.

```
[
    {name: "Something", date: "12-12-2018"},
    {name: "Something", date: "12-12-2017"},
    {name: "Something", date: "12-12-2019"},
    {name: "Something", date: "12-5-2018"},
    {name: "Something", date: "12-2-2018"},
    {name: "Something", date: "SOMETHING_INVALID"},
    {name: "Something", date: "12-12-2016"},
]
```

You can filter the valid date and future dates with a **filter** like this,

```
let dates = [
    {name: "Something", date: "1-12-2018"},
    {name: "Something", date: "2-12-2017"},
    {name: "Something", date: "3-12-2019"},
    {name: "Something", date: "4-5-2018"},
    {name: "Something", date: "5-2-2018"},
    {name: "Something", date: "InvalidSomething"},
    {name: "Something", date: "7-12-2016"},
]

let filteredDates = dates.filter((item) => {
    let date = new Date(item.date);
    if(date !== 'Invalid Date' && Date.now() < date.getTime()){
        return item;
    }
});


console.log(filteredDates);
```

**Little clarification:
`Date.now()` and `date.getTime()` both are used to get the [timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) and I am comparing inside JavaScript Filter, if the date object not returning `"Invalid Date"` string and if the **timestamp** number is bigger than today's **timestamp** then it's future date.

When those two condition matched then the `filter` it will return the whole `object` which is being collected by `filteredDates` variable. when the loop is done you will get your array for further use. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I dont't know how your data look like, but generally speaking, you need to perform two steps:

- convert strings into actual Date objects
- filter out past dates

Converting is pretty easy, just `new Date(<ISO 8601 string>)`:

```
new Date("2018-06-12"); // -> Tue Jun 12 2018 01:00:00 GMT+0100
new Date("2018-07-13"); // -> Fri Jul 13 2018 01:00:00 GMT+0100
```

Filtering out the past events can be done with [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). You give it a function that returns `True` or `False`, and it runs it for each array item. Items for which the functiuon returned `True` are put into a new array:

```
[1, 3, 4, 6, 7].filter(number => number > 4); // -> [6, 7]
[1, 3, 4, 6, 7].filter(number => number <= 4); // -> [1, 3, 4]
```

So, to filter past dates/times, you just compare them to today's date. The only tricky thing is that giving a string like `2018-06-07` (date only, without time specified) to `new Date(…)` sets the time to the current one:

```
new Date("2018-06-07"); // -> Thu Jun 07 2018 01:00:00 GMT+0100
```

If you need to compare only by days, not hours or even minutes, it's handy to set the time to past midnight:

```
(new Date("2018-06-07")).setHours(0) // -> Thu Jun 07 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100
```

So, when put together:

```js
const data = {
  events: [
    { name: "Event 1", date: "2018-06-12" },
    { name: "Event 2", date: "2018-07-10" },
    { name: "Event 3", date: "2018-07-12" },
    { name: "Event 4", date: "2018-07-13" },
    { name: "Event 5", date: "2018-08-01" }
  ]
}

const today = (new Date()).setHours(0) // past midnight

const todayAndFutureEvents = data.events.filter(event => (new Date(event.date)) >= today);

console.log(todayAndFutureEvents);
```

Another problem could arise if your events happen across multiple timezones, but that's probably out of scope of this question…

Answer (score 0):

If you pass that string to a new Date(yourString) function it will give you back a JavaScript date object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Example:

```
const newDate = new Date('2008-09-15T15:53:00')
// Will return a date object with the value of:
// Mon Sep 15 2008 15:53:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

const currentDate = Date.now();
// Will return a date object with the current date.

console.log(newDate < currentDate);
// Will compare the two dates.
```

Comment: So if I am right: I need to the Date like this>
`var eventTime = new Date (event.time)`
IF my JSON looks like this 
`''event'{
time: ''date in a string''
}'`

Comment: accidentally pressed Enter multiple times @Simeon Smith sorry.

Comment: okay. I will update on you as soon as I try it out. Thanks for help

Comment: You can then create a current date with Date.now() and compare the two.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're not really providing enough information about your JSON structure and what you have already achieved, so please add more details if this isn't enough, but something like this, I'm guessing:

```
var eventsFromMyJSONstring = JSON.parse(theJSONstringFetchedFromCertainURL);
 var currentDate = new Date();
 eventsFromMyJSONstring.forEach(function(iEvent) {
    iEvent.newVarAsDate = new Date(iEvent.textDate);
    if (iEvent.newVarAsDate >= currentDate) {
        alert('hey, this object is from today or future');
    }
});
```

edit: also, maybe you want to use filter to get just the current and future events... something like:

```
var currentAndFutureEvents = eventsFromMyJSONstring.filter((iEvent) => new Date(iEvent.textDate) >= new Date());
```

(ES6 assumed there...)